# Confused on a question on sets and functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f: R \rightarrow R$ where $f(x) = x^2$. Determine $f(A)$ for the following subset A taken from the domain R.

- A = {2,3}
- A = (-3,3)
- A = [-7,2]

So the first one I figured out to be {4,9}. I'm confused however about the other two notations. The 2nd bullet has an answers of [0,9) which I have no idea how it arrived at that.

Comment: Are you just wondering what `(-3, 3)` and `[-7, 2]` mean? Those are [open and closed intervals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Interval.html), respectively. `[0, 9)` is half-open.

Comment: I feel stupid. I guess this is what happens when you study at 1:00 in the morning. Thanks guys. Should I just delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second bullet where $A = (-3,3)$ means that $A$ is the set of all $x$ such that $-3 < x < 3$. The parenthesis imply it should be strictly less than ($<$).

The second bullet, on the other hand, has brackets which means to "include the endpoints." So for that one $A$ is the set of all $x$ such that $-7 \leq x \leq 2$.

As for what $f(A)$ would be for each of these, it would be easiest to graph them and look at the range that the function takes on over these intervals.

Answer (score 1):

The second set is the open interval from -3 to 3.  The third one is the closed interval from -7 to 2.

The answers therefore should be $[0,9)$ and $[0,49]$ respectively.